# i couldn't use preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm working on a multi platform application and I have to use preg_match_all function in php but I couldn't use it in proper way.

```
<div id="menu_background" style="background-image:url(images/menu_back_aylik.png);width:279px;height:164px;">
<div id="menu_header"><div class="one_menu_date" style="margin-left:94px;">**Çrş. 10.07.2013**</div>
    <div onclick="next();" id="nextMenu"></div>
</div>
<div id="menu_container" style="margin-left:30px;margin-top:16px;">
    <div id="menu_slider" style="width:17889px;">


            <div class="one_menu">
                <div class="one_lunchMainMenu">**lunch menu**</div>
                <div class="one_lunchAltMenu">**lunch menu alternative**</div>
                <div class="one_dinnerMainMenu">**dinner menu**</div>
                <div class="one_dinnerAltMenu">**dinner menu alternative**</div>

            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

10.07.2013 is today's date

I want to assign **lunch menu** to $lunch, **lunch menu alternative** to $lunch_a but i don't know much about preg_match_all.

Can someone help me?

**edit: I'm trying to get lunch menu from another website**

**edit2:** I'm having trouble with **regex**

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused what you're doing here. It looks like you're trying to replace **lunch menu** with a PHP variable called $lunch.

Are you just writing a PHP page that needs dynamic HTML generation? If so, you shouldn't need preg_match_all. You should be able to do this:

```
<div class="one_lunchMainMenu"><?php echo $lunch; ?></div>
```

That dynamically injects the value of $lunch into the code.

The only reason I can think of that you might need to use preg_match_all is if you have this HTML code handed to you in a variable rather than writing it yourself, and you're trying to replace parts of the code with preg_match_all.

EDIT:

After seeing your comment, it looks like you really do need to replace data in a string of HTML, rather than dynamically generating it on the fly.

Since you're trying to do a replace, I would use the `preg_replace` function instead:

```
$escaped_val = preg_quote("**lunch menu**") # Need to escape this string because it contains usual regex special chars
preg_replace( /$escapedVal/, $lunch, $yourHTMLString )
```

Comment: I'm trying to get these datas from another website by file_get_contents

Comment: It sounds like there are several issues going on here. 1) you have to obtain a string for $lunch (etc.) from another site (see Casimir's post below). 2) You want to output an HTML page with $lunch (etc.) inserted into a certain place (see dsw88's post above, the first part of it). Is that all you want to do? As an aside, I would store $lunch etc. locally in a database or in a file, to be read from the other site only once a day, so you don't have to keep hitting the other site.

Answer (score 0):

A good way is to use xpath to extract the datas:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$lunches = $xpath->query("//div[@class='one_lunchMainMenu']/text()|//div[@class='one_lunchAltMenu']/text()");
foreach($lunches as $lunch) {
    echo '<br>'. $lunch->nodeValue; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem :

```
$str=file_get_contents('target url');

preg_match_all('#<div id="menu_background"(.*?)>(.*?)<div class="one_menu_date"(.*?)>(.*?)'.date("d").'(.*?)'.date("m").'(.*?)'.date("Y").'</div>(.*?)<div class="one_lunchMainMenu">(.*?)</div>(.*?)<div class="one_lunchAltMenu">(.*?)</div>(.*?)<div class="one_dinnerMainMenu">(.*?)</div>(.*?)<div class="one_dinnerAltMenu">(.*?)</div>(.*?)</div>(.*?)</div>(.*?)</div>(.*?)</div>#si',$str,$aaa);
```